# Image Swipeview is showing same image in all activities

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I have created an application which uses imageslider with view pager using pager adapter. I have created around 5 activities with imageslider all using different images and different count of images. but when running the application on phone it is showing same image sets and same counts. Please have a look at 3 activities which are using imageslider . I am not able to Figureout the problem. 
1st activity

```
 public class customSwipe3 extends PagerAdapter {
    private int[] imageResources = {R.drawable.vcard_a,R.drawable.vcard_b,R.drawable.vcard_c,R.drawable.vcard_d,R.drawable.vcard_e};
    private Context ctxb;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflaterb;

    public customSwipe3(Context e) {
        ctxb=e;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return imageResources.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup containerb,int positionb){
        layoutInflaterb = (LayoutInflater) ctxb.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View itemView3 =layoutInflaterb.inflate(R.layout.activity_custom_swipe3,containerb,false);
        ImageView imageView3 = (ImageView)itemView3.findViewById(R.id.swip_image_view3);
        TextView textView3 =(TextView)itemView3.findViewById(R.id.imagecount3);
        imageView3.setImageResource(imageResources[positionb]);
        textView3.setText("Design No :"+positionb);
        containerb.addView(itemView3);
        return itemView3;
    }



    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup containerb ,int positionb ,Object objectb){
        containerb.removeView((LinearLayout) objectb);
    }



    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View viewb,Object objectb) {
        return (viewb==objectb);
    }
```

Code 2

```
public class customSwipe1 extends PagerAdapter {
private int[] imageResourcea = {R.drawable.brochure_a,R.drawable.brochure_b,R.drawable.brochure_c,R.drawable.brochure_d,R.drawable.brochure_e,R.drawable.brochure_f};

private Context ctxa;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflatera;

public customSwipe1(Context d) {
    ctxa=d;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return imageResourcea.length;
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup containera,int positiona){
    layoutInflatera = (LayoutInflater) ctxa.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View itemViewa =layoutInflatera.inflate(R.layout.activity_custom_swipe1,containera,false);
    ImageView imageViewa = (ImageView)itemViewa.findViewById(R.id.swip_image_view1);
    TextView textViewa =(TextView)itemViewa.findViewById(R.id.imagecount1);
    imageViewa.setImageResource(imageResourcea[positiona]);
    textViewa.setText("Brochure No :"+positiona);
    containera.addView(itemViewa);
    return itemViewa;
}



@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup containera ,int positiona ,Object objecta){
    containera.removeView((LinearLayout) objecta);
}



@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View viewa,Object objecta) {
    return (viewa==objecta);
}
```

Code 3

```
public class customSwipe4 extends PagerAdapter {


    private int[] imageResources = {R.drawable.letterheads_a,R.drawable.letterhead_b};
    private Context ctxc;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflaterc;

    public customSwipe4(Context f) {
        ctxc =f;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return imageResources.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup containerlh, int positionlh) {
        layoutInflaterc = (LayoutInflater) ctxc.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View itemView4 = layoutInflaterc.inflate(R.layout.activity_custom_swipe4, containerlh, false);
        ImageView imageView4 = (ImageView) itemView4.findViewById(R.id.swip_image_view4);
        TextView textView4 = (TextView) itemView4.findViewById(R.id.imagecount4);
        imageView4.setImageResource(imageResources[positionlh]);
        textView4.setText("Design No :" + positionlh);
        containerlh.addView(itemView4);
        return itemView4;
    }


    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup containerlh, int positionlh, Object objectlh) {
        containerlh.removeView((LinearLayout) objectlh);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View viewlh, Object objectlh) {
        return (viewlh == objectlh);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

add code where you set the adapter, adapter looks fine